# jQueryMobile listview not styling; syntax seems correct

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a listview that's dynamically generated from a JSON file as such:

```
$.getJSON('test2.json', function(data) {
                var items = [];
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    items.push('<li data-theme="c" data-icon="myapp-arrow" class="test1"><a href="#dataviewer" data-transition="slide"><p>' + key + '</p>' + val + '</a></li>');
                });
                $('<ul/>', {'data-role' : 'listview','id': 'my-new-list', 'data-divider-theme':'a', 'data-inset': 'false',html: items.join('')}).appendTo('.container');
                alert('Here is where the refresh should fire!');
                $("#my-new-list").listview("refresh");
            });
```

It adds the list items to the page, but it doesn't style them at all. Using Chromes inspector, if I copy and paste the list code into my html document, it styles just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Alert fires - just noticed the list styles correctly if I navigate to it from another page, but not if the page itself is refreshed.

Comment: Ok I suspect then it has to do with something else in your code. Can you show us more or create a jsFiddle illustrating the problem. Let me ask you this are you using using dom ready i.e $(function(){ ... }); instead of binding to pageinit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding the function to a page init and removing the "refresh" from the .listview() method solved my issue. As far as I can tell, any additional list building after this initial function should include ('#page-id').listview(refresh); and it should update just fine.

```
$( '#searchpage' ).live( 'pageinit',function(){
                $.getJSON('test2.json', function(data) {
                    var items = [];
                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                        items.push('<li data-theme="c" data-icon="myapp-arrow" class="test1"><a href="#dataviewer" data-transition="slide"><p>' + key + '</p>' + val + '</a></li>');
                    });
                    $('<ul/>', {'data-role' : 'listview','id': 'my-new-list', 'data-divider-theme':'a', 'data-inset': 'false',html: items.join('')}).appendTo('.container');
                $("#my-new-list").listview();               
                });
            });
```

Thanks to codaniel for nudging me in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

Try `$('.ui-page').trigger("create");`. You can't refresh a listview if it hasn't been created yet.